# Testing Firebase connection speed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking to build in some added layers of safety to our Android app, including a failsafe if our connection to Firebase becomes slow or disconnected. The best solution I came up with was to set up a watchdog timer that gets reset every time we get a data update from Firebase (specifically, declare a variable, decrement it every X milliseconds in a separate thread, and trigger a failsafe if the timer ever reaches zero).

Does this seem like a reasonable failsafe, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: There is already an [indicator of whether or not you're connected to Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).  What you're proposing doesn't measure connection speed, just how long it's been since you received a change.

Comment: Could I set a variable in the Android app to update to Firebase every X milliseconds, set up a Firebase function to change another variable every time that variable is changed, and then receive the changed variable back on the Android, and time that process?

Comment: Sure, but you have to understand what that is measuring.  For small amounts of data, that measures momentary round trip latency, not throughput, and those two things are not necessarily related.

Comment: Do you have any better ideas on how I could go about checking for a slow connection?